# Collection was modified, but it wasn't

Tags: c#, json, monogame

I have this two methods to cast data of session:

```cs
static void Send(string message, Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        client.Send(data);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

static void Cast(SessionInstance session)
{
    SessionInstance copiedSession = session;
    string message = Serialize(copiedSession);

    foreach (var player in copiedSession.players)
    {
        Send(message, player.ClientSocket);
    }
}

public static string Serialize(SessionInstance session)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
}
```

The `Cast` method is called from another thread. 
I copy the collection so that it is not changed by one of the threads during the loop, but the error still occurs on serialization or on foreach. 
I have tried a lot, I do not know what to do.

Comment: *"I copy the collection so that it is not changed by one of the threads during the loop"* Where is that copy operation? Note that`SessionInstance copiedSession = session;` doesn't copy anything, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Assuming that `SessionInstance` is a reference-type, `SessionInstance copiedSession = session` does not clone/copy the object. It just sets up a new reference (`copiedSession`) pointing to the very same object.

Comment: What is the type of `session.players`? Where else is it used? What's modifying it?

Comment: @spender How do I copy it completely, and not just the link to it? I've already read about how it works

Comment: @spender `session.players` - List<Player>. It is modified by a separate thread receiving data from the players

Comment: @Mootfrost Apparently, there's another thread modifying this List concurrently. You're in the territory of thread-safety here. Either use a thread-safe collection, or you'll need put locks around your access to the list to prevent mods while you copy/iterate over it.

Comment: @Mootfrost `It is modified by a separate thread` that's the problem. List isn't thread-safe. Either use a thread-safe collection like ConcurrentQueue or modify the code to use `Channel`, a high performance async collection, to produce messages from one thread or task, and consume them in another